# Is there a table of Evil keys for Dired?

Tags: evil, dired

I am learning Dired in Evil mode.
`h` `j` `k` `l` `/` are Evil keys that obviously work in Dired.
Are there others?

Is there a table of Evil keys for Dired?

I am using Emacs 25.2.1 with Evil, Spacemacs, and Ivy.

Comment: I encourage learning the default keybindings for `dired`, the interface is more reliable than overlaying `evil`, and `dired` is already optimized to have an efficient interface...you can automatically open `dired` in emacs state with `(add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes 'dired-mode)`

Comment: The [Source code](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-collection/blob/98d28bc67909225a4746c557449c9da816f5d0f5/modes/dired/evil-collection-dired.el#L41-L191) obviously show a complete table

Comment: @Henry I think any interface whose idea of "up" and "down" is "n" and "p" instead of home-row keys (assuming qwerty) is at best relatively/opinionatedly "optimized to have an efficient interface" (as opposed to both objectively and absolutely).

Comment: What I mean by my last comment is that: while there is some value in learning the Dired native interface, it's not necessarily the best we can do - it might be the best we can do *for users used to Emacs* (for example, `n` and `p` for down and up make more sense if you're already used to `C-n` and `C-p`), but they're not necessarily objectively the best keys for the job, and they're probably even less of a good fit for someone thoroughly trained up on vi-style motion. Dired also has some redundancy out-of-the-box (`e`, `f`, and `RET` all bound to `dired-find-file`, for example).

Answer (score 11):

Here are a few things you can try to see available keys:

`?` -- actually this is partly wrong because

`SPC ? dired`

`F1 m` (`describe-mode`)

`SPC h SPC dired` -- this lets you jump to the code for the layer that configures dired, `spacemacs-base`, which for key bindings purposes is mostly about keys to *run* dired rather than once you're using dired

Here are some dired keys I find useful (in fact nearly all are the same as in stock emacs, so you can also just read the info page with `F1 i` and much of it will correct key bindings still -- follow menus using `m` to go to Emacs -> Dired).

Note that 'marking' files lets you operate on multiple files at once when e.g. copying or moving files.

- `RET` or `f` Open file or directory
- `o` Open file in a separate window
- `^` Up directory
- `+` Create a directory
- `R` Rename / move
- `C` Copy
- `M` Change file/directory mode (unix file/directory permissions)
- `d` Delete
- `m` Mark
- `u` Unmark / undelete
- `x` 'Expunge' -- i.e. actually delete files/directories marked for deletion

Comment: And how do I perform the operations on all my marked files?

Comment: @Witek (responding to your comment 4 years late) you just do the operation?  e.g. if you marked some files and you want to copy them, press `C`

Answer (score 0):

I found it more helpful to approach this the other way around - what are the conflicts between Evil and Dired?

If we with Dired buffers in Evil's motion state (you can get this to be the default with `(add-to-list 'evil-motion-state-modes 'dired-mode)` in your config) we get a familiar, vi-like baseline.

Then we just need a list of what we "lose" - keys in Dired that are shadowed by Evil's motion keys, and what functions they are bound to:

| Key | Dired function | Notes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `B` | `dired-do-byte-compile` |  |
| `e` | `dired-find-file` | also bound on `RET` and `f` |
| `f` | `dired-find-file` | also bound on `RET` and `e` |
| `F` | `dired-do-find-marked-files` |  |
| `g` | `revert-buffer` |  |
| `G` | `dired-do-chgrp` |  |
| `h` | `describe-mode` | also bound on `C-h m` |
| `H` | `dired-do-hardlink` |  |
| `j` | `dired-goto-file` |  |
| `k` | `dired-do-kill-lines` |  |
| `l` | `dired-do-redisplay` |  |
| `L` | `dired-do-load` |  |
| `M` | `dired-do-chmod` |  |
| `n` | `dired-next-line` |  |
| `N` | `dired-man` |  |
| `t` | `dired-toggle-marks` |  |
| `T` | `dired-do-touch` |  |
| `v` | `dired-view-file` |  |
| `V` | `dired-do-run-mail` |  |
| `w` | `dired-copy-filename-as-kill` |  |
| `W` | `browse-url-of-dired-file` |  |
| `y` | `dired-show-file-type` |  |
| `Y` | `dired-do-relsymlink` |  |
| `!` | `dired-do-shell-command` |  |
| `#` | `dired-flag-auto-save-files` |  |
| `$` | `dired-hide-subdir` |  |
| `%` | prefix to another keymap | many commands - transforming filenames, regex-involving operations, etc |
| `^` | `dired-up-directory` |  |
| `*` | prefix to another keymap | many commands - related to Dired's marks |
| `(` | `dired-hide-details-mode` |  |
| `-` | `negative-argument` |  |
| `+` | `dired-create-directory` |  |
| `:` | prefix to another keymap | just four GPG functions (`epa-dired` / "EasyPG Assistant") |
| `?` | `dired-summary` |  |
| `RET` | `dired-find-file` | also bound on `e` and `f` |
| `C-u` | `universal-argument` | Evil only shadows this if configured to |
| `C-v` | `scroll-up-command` |  |

So with that starting point, you can just look at the standard [Dired](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Dired.html) and [Dired Extra](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/dired-x/index.html) documentation to learn what all the other keys do.

(Besides `C-d`, `C-u`, `C-v`, I didn't check modified keys for collisions between Evil motion state and Dired. I think vi/vim/Evil only use Ctrl-modified keys though, and only some of those are motions.)